# Removing xml tags by using java

Tags: java, xml

I have a very simple xml file that I would like to create a simple function to remove a tag from it. Here is my sample xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <channels>
        <channel>
            <items>
                <item>
                    <title>Java Tutorials></title>
                    <link>http://www.tutorial-point.com/</link>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <title>Java Tutorials></title>
                    <link>http://www.javatpoint.com/</link>
                </item>
            </items>
        </channel>
    </channels>
</rss>
```

In my Java program, simply want to call a method to delete two tags from the file. I'm not very familiar with XML but did manage to create a reader and writer but now I'm having trouble creating a method to delete an item from my file.

```
    // retrieve the element 
    Element element = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("channels").item(0);
    Element element2 = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("channel").item(0);
    // remove the specific node
    element.getParentNode().removeChild(element);
    element2.getParentNode().removeChild(element2);
```

When I used the above code in Java, it removed all the tags but I expected the result like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <items>
        <item>
            <title>Java Tutorials></title>
            <link>http://www.tutorial-point.com/</link>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>Java Tutorials></title>
            <link>http://www.javatpoint.com/</link>
        </item>
    </items>
</rss>
```

Can you please suggest?

Comment: Since you remove channel, you also remove its inner childs items. So to keep childs assign it to a variable and after remove of channels add child of items back.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    Element rss = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("rss").item(0);
    Element channels = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("channels").item(0);
    Element items = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("items").item(0);
    rss.appendChild(items);
    rss.removeChild(channels);
```